# Trying to grep instance id from within a text file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, grep, sh

I have a text file `bak.txt` with the following content:

```
^[[34mINFO^[[0m[0000] Your engine version 1.11.1-cs1 is compatible
^[[34mINFO^[[0m[0000] We detected local components of UCP instance H7LQ:WKR5:G2PX:4F3V:JQ47:WCIG:JV4W:V6SE:4WMR:TLZN:XYWH:MIEQ
^[[31mFATA^[[0m[0000] Re-run the command with "--id H7LQ:WKR5:G2PX:4F3V:JQ47:WCIG:JV4W:V6SE:4WMR:TLZN:XYWH:MIEQ" or --interactive to confirm you want to upgrade this UCP instance.
```

I am now trying to grep the `UCP instance` value from `bak.txt` file using the following command:

```
grep -Po '(?<=instance=)[^"]*' bak.txt
```

It is not working. Please suggest the correct way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this `grep`:

```
grep -oP '(?<=instance )[^"]+' bak.txt
```

Comment: i tried but it is giving a blank line. Please suggest

Comment: @mealhour You are doing something wrong, anubhava's regex is correct.

Comment: it seems that output is coming in black ink rather than white ink. I might need to set the `color` option too

Comment: Try: `grep --color -oP '(?<=instance )[^"]+' bak.txt`